# ¿Como obtener la semana anterior ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

Como puedo obtener las 7 fechas de la semana anterior a partir de una fecha,

Por ejemplo:

Fecha de hoy: 08/01/2019 pertenece a la 2º semana.

En este caso el resultado serían 7 fechas de la 1º semana. (Del 31/12/2018 a 06/01/2019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT F.iso_week_start_date + (Rownum-1) as Fecha
       FROM DUAL d
       CROSS JOIN ( select TRUNC(TRUNC(sysdate, 'iw') - 1,'iw')  AS iso_week_start_date
                         from dual
           ) F
       CONNECT BY Rownum <= 7
```

Salida:

```
FECHA
------------------
31.12.2018 00:00:00
01.01.2019 00:00:00
02.01.2019 00:00:00
03.01.2019 00:00:00
04.01.2019 00:00:00
05.01.2019 00:00:00
06.01.2019 00:00:00
```

Detalle:

- En primer lugar hay que determinar el primer día de la semana, usamos `sysdate` en este ejemplo, obtenemos el primer día de la semana, le restamos 1 día, para ir a la semana anterior y volvemos a calcular el primer día de la semana.
- Luego, mediante `dual` generamos una secuencia de 7 valores que combinamos con la fecha obtenida para generar los 7 días de la semana actual.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle no es mi fuerte, pero puedes hacerlo primero restando 7 dias a la fecha actual y despues obteniendo el número de la semana de esa nueva fecha.

Así puedes restar dias a una fecha:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451226/add-days-oracle-sql

Crédito a la respuesta de @mkumawat10 y traducción para en este caso 7 dias menos:

```
SELECT ( fecha - 7 ) FROM tabla;
```

Y así obtener el número de una semana:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530044/how-to-extract-week-number-in-sql

Crédito a la respuesta de @Wolf y traducción para la situación actual:

```
to_char(( fecha - 7 ),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW')
```

En este último caso 'IW' se puede reemplazar según las opciones a considerar:

```
WW  Semana del año (1-53) donde la semana 1 empieza en el primer dia del año
W   Semana del mes (1-5) donde la semana 1 empieza en el primer dia del mes
IW  Semana del año (1-52 or 1-53) basada en el estandar ISO.
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito las fechas de rango entre esa semana por ejemplo la semana 01: es desde 31/12/2018 a 06/01/2019 necesito esas fechas asi para poder sacar la data de la BD

Comment: Es decir, en el ejemplo que has puesto esperas de resultado 7 fechas, del 31/12/2018 a 06/01/2019. ¿Es eso?

Comment: O yo lo he entendido mal o esto es diferente a la pregunta original, en cualquier caso, buscando un poco por google puedes encontrar soluciones. Por ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390876/get-first-day-of-a-given-week-number-in-oracle

Comment: Si correcto porque esa semana 01 engloba las fechas 31/12/2018 a 06/01/2019 y asi sucesivamente con las semanas del año

Comment: responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad y no es correcto, además si vas a usar la respuesta de alguien mas debes traducirla y dejar los créditos al autor original, edítala por favor

Comment: @shadow tienes razón, disculpa. Ya está editada la respuesta.